# Best solution for unlocking web audio

Tags: javascript, audio, cross-browser, web-audio-api

I've been trying to think on some ideas on what I could make with JavaScript using Web Audio API. I know that depending on the user's browser I know that sometimes it won't let you play audio without a user gesture of some sort. I been doing some research on how to do it and they are pretty useful ways but the problem is that some developers found different ways to do it. For example:

1. Using a `audioContext.resume()` and `audioContext.suspend()` methods to unlock web audio by changing it's state:

```
function unlockAudioContext(context) {
    if (context.state !== "suspended") return;
    const b = document.body;
    const events = ["touchstart", "touchend", "mousedown", "keydown"];
    events.forEach(e => b.addEventListener(e, unlock, false));
    function unlock() {context.resume().then(clean);}
    function clean() {events.forEach(e => b.removeEventListener(e, unlock));}
}
```

2. creating an empty buffer and play it to unlock web audio.

```
var unlocked = false;
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
function init(e) {
    if (unlocked) return;

    // create empty buffer and play it
    var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, 1, 22050);
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);

    /* 
      Phonograph.js use this method to start it
      source.start(context.currentTime);

      paulbakaus.com suggest to use this method to start it
      source.noteOn(0);
    */

     source.start(context.currentTime) || source.noteOn(0);

     setTimeout(function() {
             if (!unlocked) {
                 if (source.playbackState === source.PLAYING_STATE || source.playbackState === source.FINISHED_STATE) {
                     unlocked = true;
                     window.removeEventListener("touchend", init, false);
                 }
             }
     }, 0);
}

window.addEventListener("touchend", init, false);
```

I know mostly how both of these methods work but
my question is what is going on here, what is the difference and which method is better etc?
And can someone please explain to me about this `source.playbackState` from an `AudioBufferSourceNode` Please? I never heard about that property on there before. It even doesn't have an article or get mentioned in the [Mozilla MDN Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode).
Also as a bonus question (which you don't have to answer), If both of these methods are useful then could it be possible to put them together as one if you know what I mean?
Sorry if that is a lot to ask. Thanks :)

resources:

https://paulbakaus.com/tutorials/html5/web-audio-on-ios/

https://github.com/Rich-Harris/phonograph/blob/master/src/init.ts

https://www.mattmontag.com/web/unlock-web-audio-in-safari-for-ios-and-macos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods work, but I find the first (resume context in a user gesture) to be cleaner.  The AudioBufferSource method is a kind of gross hack for backward compatibility with old sites that started playing buffers in a user gesture.  This method doesn't work if you don't start the buffer from a gesture. (I think.)

Which one you want to use is up to you.

Comment: am not able to get this working . Is user gesture mandatory ?. Not able to play sounds on web page load . Am using react js.

Comment: The gesture is not required by the web audiio spec, but in practice it is.  I know Chrome and Firefox require it.  I don't use react.js, so I can't help with that.  Worst case:  put a button somewhere and ask the user to press it to begin the application.  Have the button either create the context or resume the context.